# subsetting a sequence of data

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm trying to start using R for my data analysis and I have a question about subsetting a series of dataframes.

So, let's say I have data frames named i1, i2, i3, ..., i10

I would like to subset these data frames and assign the result to sub1, sub2, sub3, ..., sub10. Then combine the results.

what I want for each data frame is:

```
sub1 <- subset(i1, F < (mean(i1$F)-2*sd(i1$F)) |
                     F > (mean(i1$F)+2*sd(i$F)))
```

however with trying assign and paste, also by creating a list of i1,..,i10 but I could not achieve to do this in a for loop.

Can anyone recommend a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the datasets into a `list` with `mget`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0("i", 1:10))
```

and then do the subsetting within the `list`

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) subset(x, F > (abs(mean(F) + 2 * sd(F))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can combine all data frames into *one* large data frame and apply operations *group-wise*.

This requires that the data frames have the same structure, i.e., the same order, name, and type of columns, which seems to be the case here.

For group-wise operations on data frames we can use `data.table` or `dplyr` syntax (besides base R functions).

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
list_of_df <- mget(paste0("i", 1:10))
big_dt <- rbindlist(list_of_df, idcol = "orig.df")

big_dt[, .SD[!F %between% (mean(F) + c(-2, +2) * sd(F))], by = orig.df]
```

> ```
>    orig.df rn   F x
> 1:      i2  6  20 P
> 2:      i3  6  30 M
> 3:      i4  6  40 I
> 4:      i5  6  50 Y
> 5:      i6  6  60 U
> 6:      i7  6  70 T
> 7:      i8  6  80 F
> 8:      i9  6  90 G
> 9:     i10  6 100 F
> ```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
list_of_df <- mget(paste0("i", 1:10))
big_df <- list_of_df %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "orig.df") 

big_df %>% 
  group_by(orig.df) %>% 
  filter(!between(F, mean(F) - 2 * sd(F), mean(F) + 2 * sd(F)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 4
> # Groups:   orig.df [9]
>   orig.df    rn     F x    
>   <chr>   <int> <dbl> <chr>
> 1 i2          6    20 P    
> 2 i3          6    30 M    
> 3 i4          6    40 I    
> 4 i5          6    50 Y    
> 5 i6          6    60 U    
> 6 i7          6    70 T    
> 7 i8          6    80 F    
> 8 i9          6    90 G    
> 9 i10         6   100 F
> ```

#### Reproducible data

This will create 10 data frames in the global environment.

```
set.seed(1L)
n_row <- 6L
for (x in 1:10) {
  df_name <- paste0("i", x)
  assign(df_name,
         data.frame(
           rn = seq(n_row),
           F = c(rnorm(n_row - 1, mean = x), 10*x),
           x = sample(LETTERS, n_row, replace = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE
         ),
         envir = globalenv())
}

ls()
```

> ```
>  [1] "df_name" "i1"      "i10"     "i2"      "i3"      "i4"      "i5"      "i6"      "i7"      "i8"      "i9"     
> [12] "n_row"   "x"
> ```

Each data frame consists of 6 rows where one row contains an outlier in `F`, e.g.,

```
i3
```

> ```
>   rn         F x
> 1  1  2.983810 U
> 2  2  3.943836 O
> 3  3  3.821221 N
> 4  4  3.593901 U
> 5  5  3.918977 A
> 6  6 30.000000 M
> ```